# C# TCP Socket Programming - Sending Data to All Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, server, client

I am working on server/multiple client programming. I will cut the chase everything is working well but

```
foreach(Socket sct in socketArray){
        sct.send(data);
}
```

is not working. It suppose to send data to all connected sockets but only the one who made request getting the response. I was thinking if it is related to tcp packaging? or i dont know why it is not working? If somebody can help i would be really appriciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming `data` is `byte[]` and that you mean `sct.Send`, then: it should work fine, and send the same payload - sequentially - to all the sockets in `socketArray`. There isn't anything particularly nuanced here - each socket is independent.

Things to check:

- does `socketArray` actually have the expected number of sockets?
- are they the *correct* sockets?
- is an exception happening?
- are the sockets actually connected? (broken sockets are notoriously hard to detect reliably)
- do you have `NoDelay` enabled?
- is there some concurrency here that could mean that a single socket is trying to send twice at the same time?
- is it sending, and the error is in the receive code?

Comment: i checked sockedarray in debug and it has right socket i checked their remote ip it looked okey. There is no exception whatsoever like i told on the request side it works fine. But i want other clients to get request same requesting client. I dont know what is NoDelay

Comment: @EmirhanÖzsoy `NoDelay` is a boolean on `Socket`; you probably want it to be `true`. However, ultimately I strongly suspect that the problem here is more client-related than server-related. The code *looks* OK.

Comment: Thanks i did it! Problem was in the code it starts listening when i get request so other clients wasnt starting to listening without request not it is working.